# media query for iphone is not working in magento?

Tags: html, css

i am using the media query for iphone 5s . but it is not working in the mobile device. the view of the site remains same. I am using media query for this [website](http://blindandscreen.com)  , you can check it there and in your iphone device also.

```
    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) and (orientation : portrait) {
    .wrapper {
    min-width: auto;
    width: 100% ;
    float: left ;
    }
    .nav-container {
    background: url(../images/nav.png) no-repeat;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    }
    .page{
    width: 92%;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
    .header,.header-container{
    width: 100% ;
    float:left ;
    }
   .header .logo {
    margin: 3% auto 0;
    width:100%;
    }
   .header .logo img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
    }
    .quick-access {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2% 1%;
    width: 98%;
    }
    .header .welcome-msg {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 ;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    }
    .header .links {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 4% 1%;
    width: 94%;
    }
    .header .links li {
    background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0) url("../images/tsp.gif") no-repeat scroll 100% 8px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 3% 0 0;
    padding: 2% 3% 2% 0;
    }
    .main-container {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15%;
    padding: 5% 4%;
    width: 92%;
    }
    .main {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    }
    .col3-layout .col-wrapper {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 99%;
    }
    }
```

in my browser [image: i am getting this on my browser]
in iphone 5s [image: i am getting this in my iphone]

Comment: You will need to post the code which is causing issue to you.

Comment: i dont know what is the cause of the issue . Media query is working but the view remains same. Looks like there is a issue in width . but i am not able to sort out this problem

Comment: Show us your media query. _Here. Within your question._ You can't expect us to go searching through your source and guessing which piece of code you are talking about.

Comment: this is my code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because there is a div having class wrapper has max-width ,due to which the page doesn't fits according to the mobile screen and it is in pixel . i have change this to percentage and all starts working good .